# input in nested form is not shown in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a Rails app that has two models: Question and possible answer. A question has many possible answers and a possible answer belongs to a question. While adding question, I'd like to add possible answers. However, I can't make possible answers input shown. Here are files may cause the problem:

`questions_controller.rb`:

```
  def new
    @question = @poll.questions.build
    4.times { @question.possible_answers.build }
  end
```

`question.rb`:

```
has_many :possible_answers

accepts_nested_attributes_for :possible_answers
```

`_form.html.haml`:

```
-f.fields_for :possible_answers do |p|
  =p.text_field :title
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haa... I see that. Took me a while though.

In `erb`, the difference between `<% ... %>` and `<%= ... %>` is that the former only analyses, while the later shows the result as well.

The same principle applies when other engines are being used as well (`slim`, `haml`, etc).

To analyse, use `-`, but to display as well, use `=`.

So, to apply the above to your case, the line for the nested attributes has to be changed from only analysing, to also displaying.

That is: change this:

```
-f.fields_for :possible_answers do |p|
  =p.text_field :title
```

to this:

```
=f.fields_for :possible_answers do |p|
  =p.text_field :title
```

and that should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
= f.fields_for :possible_answers do |p|
  =p.text_field :title
```

When I first started Rails, it took me a day to figure that out.